# onClick function not working with View Binding Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, android-viewbinding

I am a beginner in kotlin, trying to develop sample projects. I tried using View.OnClickListener interface to get Id of any view clicked in my layout. I have 9 buttons in my layout (tic tac toe game) but when the code is run nothing happens on clicking any buttons, its not even showing any errors.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    var active = 1
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        val button = view as Button
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
        if(active == 1) {
            button.text = "X"
            button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6200EE"))
            button.textSize = 20f
            button.isEnabled = false
            active = 0
        }
        else {
            button.text = "O"
            button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6200EE"))
            button.textSize = 20f
            button.isEnabled = false
            active = 1
        }
    }
}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#F6F6F6">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/trRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bnOne"
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="40pt"
                android:layout_marginRight="5pt"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bnTwo"
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="40pt"
                android:layout_marginRight="5pt"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bnThree"
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="40pt"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/trRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bnFour"
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="40pt"
                android:layout_marginRight="5pt"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bnFive"
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="40pt"
                android:layout_marginRight="5pt"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bnSix"
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="40pt"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/trRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bnSeven"
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="40pt"
                android:layout_marginRight="5pt"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bnEight"
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="40pt"
                android:layout_marginRight="5pt"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bnNine"
                android:layout_width="40pt"
                android:layout_height="40pt"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add your xml file to your question?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't attached instance of buttonClickListener with Acitivty View.OnClickListener

For that you need to add line

```
button.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Below is implemantation of how to attach onClick listener with button instances

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.bnOne.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.bnTwo.setOnClickListener(this)
        ................
        ................
        ................
        binding.bnNine.setOnClickListener(this)
        
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but it was my mistake in the question. Since the above mentioned method was not working I implemented the functionality by this method. I forgot to change the code while posting. Question is now updated. The real problem is, onClick function is not invoking when a click is registered in the layout. I had done the same functionality before using Java by implementing onClickListener interface, so when ever a click is registered in the layout it will automatically call the overridden onClick functoin. But when I tried to do the same using Kotlin nothing is happening.

Comment: Thank You, but what if am adding these buttons dynamically from backend. Then how can I get the ID's of any button clicked?

Comment: OnClick after casting view into button, then button.getId() funcation will fetch and check will xml id like (button.getId() == R.id.bnOne) this will give status of id's match

Comment: Yeah got it, but the real problem am facing is, OnClick function is not invoking on any registered click. If the buttons are dynamic then I may not be able to call setOnClickListener method for all the buttons in the program.